# Probability of being able to make an $m$-gon after breaking a stick in $n$ pieces - How to approach this problem?

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-theory, inequality

Let's be given a stick of length $1$ and now repeatedly break the longest side of it in pieces, so you end up with $n$ smaller sticks. How likely is it to be able  form a certain $m$-gon?

I think this problem is quite well known for: $m = n = 3$ and I believe one can also use its "standard" solution to compute the probability for any given $m,n$.

However this approach seems to me quite cumbersome and makes me wonder, if there isn't a better approach to this problem and I would be most happy, if someone with a deeper understanding of this matter, could provide his/her thoughts.

Since a direct answer to this generalization might be a bit tricky, I were satisfied, if someone could simply reference a paper, article or discussion to a similar problem, maybe above problem + further assumptions to make it more approachable. As always thanks for any constructive comment and/or answer.

Comment: The issue with these problems is that you have to be careful about stating how you cut the stick, i.e. what probability distribution you are going to use...

Comment: It seems that the distribution is given by picking a longest piece and breaking it at a uniformly distributed point.

Comment: You should provide or link to the 'well-known' solution, and state what you are trying and where you are stuck. The problem does not seem that easy to solve with a generic n, even if $n=m$